# Are there any chemical pathways or catalysts that could produce electricity from fossil fuels without combustion?

Tags: electrochemistry, catalysis, fuel, green-chemistry

While fossil fuels are dense in energy, I have known only one way to retrieve energy from them, namely, to burn them. I wish we could have a way to get energy from them without combustion.

Is there any way we could get energy from oil, gas, diesel or other fossil fuels without burning them? Ideally, so we could making something like a battery out of them.

Comment: If you mean, can you get energy out of it without breaking bonds? Not really. I doubt you would get very far trying to take electrons from it either.

Comment: Check out fuel cells. Usually they require hydrogen as fuel, and the hydrogen often comes from processing of fossil fuels. However, some kinds of fuel cells have been developed that can directly use hydrocarbons as fuel.

Comment: Even if this was easy (it is possible but not easy0 it would not be much of an advantage. A fuel cell could generate electricity from oxidation reactions (and such fuel cells using methane are known) but the products re the same as burning and the overall efficiencies are not good enough to justify the overall cost in most circumstances.